# AMP. No anchor element found

Tags: amp-html, adsense, adsense-anchor-ads

[image]
I set up **Auto ads** for the AMP version of a website I'm developing. But ads didn't appear due to warning – **"No anchor element found"**. It means AdSense' script can't find an appropriate tag on a page to put ad into one.

On [the official documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-auto-ads/) I found next:

> The configuration defines where on the page  can place
>   ads. The configuration is fetched from a third-party ad network at the
>   URL defined in ad-network-config.js

And I found the config and selectors there where `<amp-auto-ads>` can place ads.
[image]

These selectors are weird because on the website there's no the tag `<div id="post-container">` on any page (the tag never existed). of course I can make changes to the website and add this tag, but what if selectors are changed again? I have to make it over again and again...

So, **can I do something to ask AdSense to update placements into the config for the website?** I failed to find information about it on the internet at all. It looks like AdSense made a mistake and gave the wrong placements for the website.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems like a known bug, see here => https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/26934 with some people this seems to go away after some time. Did it work for you at some point and stopped working, or did it never work in your case?

Comment: How is your site structured? Each HTML page has an AMP version which is accessible by adding /amp suffix to url?

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau yes, to get AMP version of a page you can add /amp postfix. You can see it on screenshots above.

Comment: @stylesuxx thank you for the link to the issues. It helped me to find the way made AdSense change selectors into the config.

I'm not sure but I think that AdSense generate selectors based on regular pages structure (regular web pages, not AMP). When I made change HTML structure on web pages then the config from AdSense was changed too in a few hours and ads appeared on pages.